# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code iOS

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I have downloaded a project which is developed by someone other. after downloading I have updated all pods , then when I am going to run the project its showing an error like :

**`Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code`**

I have tried by lock unlock my login on key chain. I think my certification is from different account . is it a problem ?
pods are used : -

```
pod 'AmplifyPlugins/AWSAPIPlugin'
  pod 'Amplify'
  pod 'Amplify/Tools'
  pod 'AmplifyPlugins/AWSDataStorePlugin'
  pod 'SideMenu'
```

[here is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqxu9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was solved the problem,

it was showing this error for versioning of pod. I have search and found the current version of pod, then updated them to latest.
by upgrading latest pod, I need to change some codes like function name delegates etc.
then it solved the problem .

```
pod 'AmplifyPlugins/AWSAPIPlugin' // using correct version
  pod 'Amplify' // using correct version
  pod 'Amplify/Tools' // using correct version
  pod 'AmplifyPlugins/AWSDataStorePlugin' // using correct version
  pod 'SideMenu // using correct version
```

'